# Disable Exception In C#

Tags: c#, exception

I have c# program, This Get Sql Query From Input and Execute this.
Some times, This Query contain any words that after execute query, return ***"Divide By Zero Exception"***.

I want disable *SqlException* **Before** Execute Query and check Other entered word and then enable this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called **Try...Catch**.

Read about it [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: this isn't my problem. i perfectlly dominance to try...catch operation

Comment: @AmirReza, I somewhat dare to doubt it. Try-catch blocks are used exactly in this type of situations. John's answer is precise.

Comment: dear john. I want disable SqlException before Execute sql query to prevent this execption but enable all other exception. then after execute query enable SqlException qgain.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do that. Please add a lot more detail to your question and include your source code and what the problem is that you are trying to fix. It sounds like you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I have a Program like formula editor for compile Sql Expression which combination sql expression and user expresson (user expression is table fields or sql custom function). after execute query i encounter with "Devide By Zero Exception" message. that message is not important in Test time. (test time check query for wronge word). So i want prevent as this exception in Test time

Comment: My answer still works, trap the error in a try catch, and then don't show it to the user if you don't want to. What does it matter if the error happens behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

So many times, one simply doesn't need exceptions at all.

For example, if I open a file and use the wrong name, or its busy or whatever,

The return of the operation is null.   That is enuf for me to surmise,
I asked for something, and it didn't work.

But no, I have to surround my code with all kinds of funny business.

```
StreamReader streamReader=new StreamReader(filename);
if (streamReader==null)
  Console.WriteLine("File Not Ready To Be Read {0}!",filename)
else
  {
  //go on with your business
  }
```

//CONTRAST WITH THIS THAT COMPILES ONLY BECAUSE I HAD TO CATCH NOTHING AND DO NOTHING AND FINALLY DO WHAT EVER IT WAS I WAS FOCUSSED ON.
using System;
using System.IO;

```
class ExceptionHandling
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader streamReader = null;
        try
        {
        streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\bin\\C#\\readfil1e\\data.txt");//or @"c:\bin\c#\readfile\data.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        if (streamReader == null)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("FILE NOT READABLE");
            Console.ReadLine();
          }
        else
          {
          Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
          Console.ReadLine();
          streamReader.Close();
          }
        }//finally

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer to the question but I wholeheartedly agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Hes maybe looking for #pragma to disable exception, when hes not looking for try and catch